# Google sign in API inconsistently returns givenName and familyName as "null"

Tags: android, react-native, google-api, google-signin

We have an app in Google Play that has been working just fine. It is built with react-native and the iOS version is still working just fine. Starting this morning, when users sign in with google sign in, SOME of them return the givenName and familyName as "null". Not a null value, but a string of "null".

[image: Returned JSON with familyName: "null"]

This is happening to our existing app in Google Play, as well as our new version. We are using a deprecated version of react native google sign in (v2.0.0), which we are trying to switch off of, but we still need to deal with the versions already in the wild. Also, the behavior is not consistent. As I said, no issues on iOS, and even on Android, signing in with a given account returns "null" strings one minute, and the normal data five minutes later.

I should have mentioned, it is treated as a successful login. The email is returned correct. Oddly, the name field, which should be the full name, is not "null", but just the email again.

Anyone else seeing this issue, or aware of what we may be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing. Anyone know whats going on?